# Matrix mean of values >x

Tags: matlab, matrix, mean, large-data

I need to compute the mean of a matrix but only for those values that are greater than a specified number. Right now I come with this idea:

```
Media = mean(W_tot_migl,2);

H = W_tot_migl;
H(H<LimiteInferiore) = nan;
Media_b = nanmean(H,2);
```

Is there any way to avoid to create another matrix `H = W_tot_migl`?

Comment: Note that your solution currently tries to take the mean of values `>= x`, rather than `> x`. Make sure to decide what you want and include this in your final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matrix `H` and threshold `T` you can use:

```
M = nanmean(H+0./(H>T),2);
```

in your case:

```
Media_b = nanmean(W_tot_migl+0./(W_tot_migl>LimiteInferiore),2);
```

OR calculate it yourself:

```
M = sum(H.*(H>T),2)./sum(H>T,2);
```

For your case:

```
Media_b = sum(W_tot_migl.*(W_tot_migl>LimiteInferiore),2)./sum(W_tot_migl>LimiteInferiore,2);
```

Note that both methods return `NaN` if there are no values greater than the threshold in a row.

However, in general you can use `accumarray` to accomplish this:

```
H2 = H>T;
[I,~] = find(H2);
M = accumarray(I, H(H2), [size(H,1) 1], @mean);
```

This method returns zero if there are no elements larger than the threshold in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments you want this:

```
H = magic(5); %Suppose this is your matrix
LimiteInferiore = 23; %And suppose this is your treshold

Media_b= NaN(size(H,1),1); %Or perhaps zeros, whatever you like to show by default

idx = any(H > treshold,2);
Media_b(idx) = mean(H(H>treshold),2);
```

It will give you the rowmean if it exists, and NaN otherwise. I believe you won't need NaN mean as NaN values won't evaluate as `>treshold`.